# doPost(e) function working partially

Tags: google-sheets

I have this code, it suppose to get info from external source, send message back to this source asking for desired action and then analyze this response, if the response have '@' in the text, it will write "closed" in some specific cell and then send message that confirm this action.

eventually, it never worked. the first message is sent, but the second message - not. and also the specific cell is not changing.

how can i know where is my problem?

```
 function doPost(e) 
    {
      var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
      var text = contents.message.text;
      var id = contents.message.from.id;
      var name = contents.message.from.first_name + " " + 
      contents.message.from.last_name;
      sendText(id, 'Hi ' + name ,' please send your needed action'); //till here, everything works great


      if (/^@/.test(text))
      {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ServiceC");
        SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
        var getCallID = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
        getCallID = parseInt(getCallID,10);
        var cellToEdit = 'K' + (getCallID + 8) ;
        sheet.getRange(cellToEdit).setValue("close");
        sendText(id, 'now its closed');
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it ! the text slicing was wrong. i fixed it and it's working like a charm!